# How to load partial view in <DIV> tag?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am still learning MVC. I am having problem with Partial View. I have a page with dropdown value. And whenever user choose the value, a partial page with datatable will appear.

Currently, i am thinking of using JQuery load function to load the page into the div tag. But the datatable is not showing. Is there something wrong with my code or is it any better way of doing this? Please help. Thank you.

My View:

```
    @model MVCWeb.Models.DP_Table
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Data Patching";
}

<br />

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<br />

<table class="table-striped table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="40%">
                <label class="control-label">Select Table</label>
            </td>
            <td width="10%">:</td>
            <td width="*%">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.DPTableID, new SelectList(Model.TableCollection,
                "DPTableId", "TableName"), "Please Select", new { @id = "ddTableName", @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Select Action</label>
            </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("Actions", @ViewBag.PatchingActions as List<SelectListItem>,
                "Please Select", new { @id = "ddPatchingAction", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<div id="divPatching"></div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var ddTableValue, ddPatchingActionValue;

        $('#ddTableName').change(function () {
            ddTableValue = $('#ddTableName option:selected').val();
            if (ddTableValue) {
                $("#ddPatchingAction").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $("#ddPatchingAction").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });

        $('#ddPatchingAction').change(function () {
            ddPatchingActionValue = $('#ddPatchingAction option:selected').val();
            if (ddPatchingActionValue) {
                $("#divPatching").load('@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "DataPatching")');
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

My Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/PatchingBatch/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

My Partial View:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px" onclick="AddUserForm('@Url.Action("AddUser", "Account")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New User</a>
<table id="batchTable" class="table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Is Admin</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var popup, dataTable;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable = $("#batchTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Account/GetDPUserList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Username", "name":"Username" },
                    { "data": "Name", "name": "Name"  },
                    { "data": "Email", "name": "Email"  },
                    { "data": "IsAdmin", "name": "IsAdmin" },
                    {
                        "data": "DPUserID", "render": function (data) {
                            return "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick=EditUserForm('@Url.Action("UpdateUser", "Account")/" + data +"')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'  style='margin-left: 5px' onclick=Delete(" + data +")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                        },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "width": "150px"
                    },

                ],

                "processing": "true",
                "serverSide": "true",
                "order": [0, "asc"]
            });
        });

        function AddUserForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');

            $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {
                    formDiv.html(response);

                    popup = formDiv.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: "Add User Account",
                        height: 250,
                        width: 300,
                        close: function () {
                            popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
        }

        function EditUserForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');

            $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {
                    formDiv.html(response);

                    popup = formDiv.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: "Update User Account",
                        height: 410,
                        width: 300,
                        close: function () {
                            popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
        }

        function SubmitForm(form) {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

            if ($(form).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.action,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            popup.dialog('close');
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();

                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        function Delete(id) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Account")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();
                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
                )
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

My Partial Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDPUserList()
{
    //server side parameter
    int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
    string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
    string sortColumnName = Request["columns[" + Request["order[0][column]"] + "][name]"];
    string sortDirection = Request["order[0][dir]"];

    List<DP_User> userList = new List<DP_User>();
    using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
    {
        userList = db.DP_User.ToList<DP_User>();
        userList = userList.ToList<DP_User>();
        int totalrows = userList.Count();

        //search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
        {
            userList = userList.Where(x => (x.Username != null && x.Username.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue)) ||
            (x.Name != null && x.Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue)) ||
            (x.Email != null && x.Email.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue))).ToList<DP_User>();
        }

        int totalrowsafterfilter = userList.Count();

        //sorting
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortDirection))
        {
            userList = userList.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList<DP_User>();
        }

        //paging
        userList = userList.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList<DP_User>();

        return Json(new { data = userList, draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalrows, recordsFiltered = totalrowsafterfilter },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Is your `GetPartialView` action called after changing dropdown value? Are there any errors in the console? Do you have anything displayed inside `#divPatching`? Is your `GetDPUserList` action called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Create One `Partial View` To Name Of `Page`

2-Create One `Action`

```
public ActionResult YourPage()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Page.cshtml");
    }
```

3-To Your View Create One `div`

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

4-Write This Code To `script`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("/Home/YourPage", function (data) {
            $('#MyDiv').html(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ASP.NET core you can use this command

```
<partial name="_yourPartial" />
```

it will load the view for you from a method in the controller

if you are in an older version of ASP.NET you can use this older command

```
@Html.Partial("_yourPartial")
```

it works the same way, and avoid using jquery

you can also pass a model through it, using the command

```
@Html.Partial("_yourPartial", new { paramName = "foo" })
```

Comment: I am planning to use jQuery because different partial view will be called based on the value user chooses from the dropdown. And all this partial view has datatable